# update-database command in EF6 not working after initial migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I got stuck at command:

```
update-database
```

while going through this [tutorial by Tom Dysktra](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Here is the error I am getting:

```
    PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'EmailAddress'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

...

```
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the verbose command? I usually do the following in the console

```
update-database -force -verbose
```

It also says no pending migrations. I am going to take shot in the dark and guess you have automatic migrations turned off. which means before you can update-database you need to create a migration

```
add-migration NameItSomethingMeaningful
```

Now you can update-database

Answer (score 0):

This means that in your seed calls you have some invalid SQL call happening - specifically you have a query that gets back a value which probably doesn't fit the type you are trying to cast it into.